# AngularJs 1, input type having value to update dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Hello guys i'm trying something out in angular and i'm struck in between, we can assign values to input element for eg, where parameters is a list of parameters and is in ng repeat

```
<input type="text" ng-model="parameters.inParameterName" class="form-control number"  value="{{parameters.inParameterName = current}}"/>
```

^This works but when i try to get right hand side of value from backend ie in that parameter variable

```
<input type="text" ng-model="parameters.inParameterName" class="form-control number"  value="{{parameters.inParameterName = parameters.formula}}"/>
```

the text box ng model is assigning to that string and i'm not able to edit the field

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign a value from your database to model parameter in controller file.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
// just assign then value of textDemo what ever you like ie you can set from database value or static depends upon you.
 $scope.textDemo = 'Testing';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="textDemo" />
     </div>
</div>
```